# Google Cloud API sentiment analysis

Tags: google-cloud-nl

I was going through Google Cloud API for sentiment analysis. The thing which is not clear to me is that on what basis the sentiment scores and magnitudes are assigned? Is there any kind of lexicon or any kind of training data? Is there any algorithm which can clarify how sentiment score is assigned?

Comment: I think, they are using the data available at Google to build the sentiment analysis model (probably neural nets) and open sourced the API for us to use it on the test(production) data.

Answer (score 0):

I work in Cloud Natural Language team at Google. What's mentioned in the above comment is correct. We have built models internally (neural nets) and exposing them via the API basically.